# CSS is not always gzipped why?

Tags: gzip, varnish

In my Firefox or Chrome if I check the HTTP header the result are always with Content-Encoding: gzip. But I have customers reporting that they see "transfer-encoding: chunked" instead and the request are not gzipped.

http://www.example.com/public/css/style.min.css

If I or the customer do a gzip compression online check it's confirmed gzip is active.

https://checkgzipcompression.com = gzip!

But if I use a checker like this one. http://onlinecurl.com/

I also get the transfer-encoding: chunked

Request:

```
GET /style/css.css HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
User-Agent: ...
Accept: /
Referer: http://www.example.com/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: ...
Cookie: ...
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Age: 532948
cache-control: public, max-age=604800
Content-Type: text/css
Date: Wed, 28 Jun 2017 12:35:07 GMT
ETag: "5349e8d595dfd21:0"
Last-Modified: Wed, 07 Jun 2017 13:56:17 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Vary: X-UA,Accept-Encoding, User-Agent
X-Cache: HIT
X-Cache-Hits: 6327
X-CacheReason: Static-js-css.
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Served-By: ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xx.name.xxx
x-stale: true
X-UA-Device: pc
X-Varnish: 993020034 905795837
X-Varnish-beresp-grace: 43200.000
X-Varnish-beresp-status: 200
X-Varnish-beresp-ttl: 604800.000
transfer-encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
```

Why are some requests not gzipped, when it should, this is my Varnish config (the part relevant for gzip):

```
if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
    if (req.url ~ "\.(jpg|png|gif|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp3|ogg|flv|swf)$") {
  # No point in compressing these
     remove req.http.Accept-Encoding;
    } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
  set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
 } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate") {
  set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
  } else {
   # unkown algorithm
    remove req.http.Accept-Encoding;
   }
}

# Enabling GZIP
if (beresp.http.Content-Type ~ "(text/css|application/x-javascript|application/javascript)") {
  set beresp.do_gzip = true;
}


if (beresp.http.Content-Encoding ~ "gzip" ) {
  if (beresp.http.Content-Length == "0") {
    unset beresp.http.Content-Encoding;
  }
}  

set beresp.http.Vary = regsub(beresp.http.Vary, "(?i)^(.*?)X-Forwarded-URI,?(.*)$", "\1\2");
set beresp.http.Vary = regsub(beresp.http.Vary, "(?i)^(.*?)User-Agent,?(.*)$", "\1\2");
set beresp.http.Vary = regsub(beresp.http.Vary, "^(.*?),?$", "X-UA,\1");
set beresp.http.Vary = regsub(beresp.http.Vary, "^(.*?),?$", "\1");
```

Any ideas, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Responses will only be gzipped if the request indicates that it can accept a gzipped response. This is indicated by the `Accept-Encoding` header in the request. So perhaps your online `curl` is not sending that header. It may be the same for your clients who are seeing this. You really have customers who are reporting that they are not getting responses gzipped?

**Update**

Ah, I see what you're doing now. Are you using a recent version of Varnish? There's no need to do all this yourself now. Varnish handles it all natively. All you need to do is set `do_gzip` to `on` for the content types where you want it, and Varnish takes care of the rest, including the `Accept-Encoding` header. See [the documentation here](http://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/users-guide/compression.html).

So just remove all of your gzip/encoding related code except the part directly under `# Enabling GZIP`:

```
# Enabling GZIP
if (beresp.http.Content-Type ~ "(text/css|application/x-javascript|application/javascript)") {
  set beresp.do_gzip = true;
}
```

And that will probably get everything working. It works fine for me that way. The best amount of VCL is as little as possible, Varnish is very good at handling things itself. Don't forget to restart Varnish or otherwise clear the cache for this site after making the change.

In case it's useful, I use the following VCL for this:

```
if (
    beresp.status == 200
    && beresp.http.content-type ~ "\b((text/(html|plain|css|javascript|xml|xsl))|(application/(javascript|xml|xhtml\+xml)))\b"
) {
    set beresp.do_gzip = true;
}
```

Which checks for more content types that can benefit from compression, including HTML. I don't bother with `application/x-javascript` as it's ancient and not used.

On another note, are you sure you need to be modifying the `Vary` header in the way that you are doing there?

Comment: My request includes Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, but response are still not gzipped and with Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Comment: I think it would be best to post all your VCL.

Comment: Updated the post with the part relevant for gzip. Let me know if you need the full VCL. Thank you.